# C++ compiler does not check if a method exists in template class

Tags: c++, templates, definition-checking

I came across with the following program in `C++`:

```
template <class T>
class Val {
protected:
    T x0, x;
public:
    Val(T t = 1) : x0(t), x(1) {}
    T val() { return x; }
    void promote() { this->promote_value(); }
};
```

For some reason `Val<int>(4).val();` works fine even though there is no method `promote_value()`. I tried to remove the templates:

```
class OtherVal {
protected:
    int x0, x;
public:
    OtherVal (int t = 1) : x0(t), x(1) {}
    int val() { return x; }
    void promote() { this->promote_value(); }
};
```

But now I get an error:

> error: ‘class OtherVal’ has no member named ‘promote_value’; did you mean ‘promote’?

Why does `C++` behave like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Template class methods are not instantiated until they are used. Once you try calling `promote()` or even get its address like this `&Val<int>::promote` then you'll get an error.

From the C++ standard:

> § 17.8.1.10 An implementation shall not implicitly instantiate a function
>   template, a variable template, a member template, a non-virtual member
>   function, a member class, a static data member of a class template,
>   or a substatement of a constexpr if statement (9.4.1), unless such
>   instantiation is required.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any checks at all that the compiler does on `promote()`? I guess syntax errors.

Comment: @vesil, AFAIK the compiler is obligated by the standard to parse the non-instantiated method definition and check it for correctness as much as it can without knowing the `T`. However the MSVC is known for violating that requirement and not bothering to check anything thus allowing a complete nonsense in method definition which will only be discovered when the method is actually used.

Comment: So if the method `promote()` is virtual it will fail in compilation?

Comment: @vesii, yes, actually it will, because making it virtual will make the compiler **implicitly take its address** in order to put it into a virtual table.

Answer (score 9):

Templates have always worked this way, principally to facilitate their use.

Because `Val<int>(4).val();` doesn't *call* `promote`, that function is not compiled for your particular instantiation of that template so the compiler does not issue a diagnostic.

Many metaprogramming techniques depend on this behaviour.